# how to close an outlook appointmentItem using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, outlook-2007, appointment

I have a custom form that I want to take full control of the appointmentItem thats open, When the user clicks the button I want the item and the data to save (which I have), **but I want the Window to close as well...**

```
const olAppointmentItem = 9
Sub btn_create_Click()
MsgBox " wtf!!"

'get aplpication context
Dim myOutlook 
Set myOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'get shell access
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

'get the namespace for access to shipping folder
Dim myNameSpace 
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(9)

'get the location of the shipping folder
Dim myFolder
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.Parent
Set mySharedFolder= myNameSpace.Parent.Folders("Shipping")


' Create a new appointment.
Set olAppt = mySharedFolder.Items.Add  

'declare vars to pull from the form
Set oPage = Item.GetInspector.ModifiedFormPages
Set ship_company = oPage("Shipping").Controls("tb_CompanyName")
Set ship_date = oPage("Shipping").Controls("tb_shipDate")
Set ship_address = oPage("Shipping").Controls("tb_address")
Set ship_freighter = oPage("Shipping").Controls("tb_freighter")
Set ship_truck_type = oPage("Shipping").Controls("tb_truckType")
'TODO : need to figure out way for bv numbers because of multiline

'split the date value so it plays nice
Dim temp
temp = ship_date.text
Dim realDate
realDate = split(ship_date," ",2)


' Setup other appointment information...
With olAppt  
'   .Start = #10/4/2014 9:00 PM#
.Start = realDate(1)
  .Duration = 0
  .Subject = "Meeting to discuss plans..."
  .Body = "Meeting with fRANK    to discuss plans."
  .Location = "Home Office"
  .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 0
  .ReminderSet = false
.Save   

End With


'Save and close Appointment...
olAppt.Close (olSave)

Set myOutlook = Nothing
MsgBox "Done!"

end Sub
```

I'm EXTREMELY new to VBScript but the .close function just isn't working, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear from the VBA that anything was displayed but

```
myOutlook.Quit
Set myOutlook = Nothing
```

should close Outlook if it is open.